# save not working when using a has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a lead object that was being saved fine. Now I added a has_one association between leads and campaigns. A campaign has one lead, where lead has the foreign key campaign_id. And I have the following in my models:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :lead
end

class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

In my leads controller create action I have this:

```
def create
    campaign = Campaign.find_by id: params[:campaign_id]
    @lead = campaign.build_lead lead_params

    if @lead.save
      redirect_to lead_path
    else
    end
  end
```

Lead object is never saved. It's not in the database. And it's id value is nil, even though the if condition passes. I also tried @lead.save! and @lead.save(validate: false). How can I figure out what the error is?

In order to get this to work, I have to remove the belongs_to :campaign in the Lead model. And I have to save it like this:

```
campaign = Campaign.find_by_id(params[:campaign_id].to_i)
@lead = Lead.new lead_params

if @lead.save
  @lead.campaign_id = campaign.id
  @lead.save!
```

Comment: Please post your `new` method and `lead_params` method.

Comment: If the Lead class has an attribute that masked a core rails method that would explain things - post the columns the table has so we can have a look

Comment: @FrederickCheung you were right, it was masked by a core rails method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need save the `campain`, instead of only `@lead`...

When you save the `campain`, it will also save his nested object and maintain the relationship.

So try it:

```rb
def create
  campaign = Campaign.find_by id: params[:campaign_id]
  @lead = campaign.build_lead lead_params

  if campain.save
    redirect_to lead_path
  else
  end
end
```

Comment: how trouble is put a debugger and try recover campaing.errors or @lead.errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just saving a "plain" `Lead`, why not try the following:

--

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :campaigns do
   resources :leads
end

#app/controllers/leads_controller.rb
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @campaign = Campaign.find params[:campaign_id]
      @lead = @campaign.build_lead
   end

   def create
      @campaign = Campaign.find params[:campaign_id]
      @lead = @campaign.lead.new lead_params

      if @lead.save

      end
   end

   private

   def lead_params
      params.require(:lead).permit(:lead, :attributes)
   end
end

#app/models/lead.rb
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
   # validations etc
end

#app/views/leads/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @lead do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :lead %>
   <%= f.text_field :attributes %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This should work *if* you're passing the lead as a plain object (IE not as nested attributes of a `Campaign` object). The other issues you may have will include your validations preventing `Lead` from being saved, or that your params are not being built & sent correctly

If the above doesn't work for you, I'd recommend uploading the `params` you receive from your `new` action - if you get these, we'll be in a much stronger position to help you discern what's going on.

Comment: I don't think this will work. If you do it like this `params[:campaign_id]` in `create` will be `nil`.